# Recording Personal Loan

Tags: gnucash, personal-loan, bookkeeping

If I put $200 of groceries on my credit card for a friend while I'm out shopping, how do I record that transaction? Further, when she pays me back by bank transfer, how do I record that transaction to distinguish it from income? I'm using GnuCash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I put $200 of groceries on my credit card for a friend while I'm
> out shopping, how do I record that transaction

Debit Current Asset:Debtor/Receivable:Friend

Credit Current Liability:Credit Card

> how do I record that transaction, and when she pays me back by bank
> transfer

Debit Current Asset:Bank

Credit Current Asset:Debtor/Receivable:Friend

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'm still wrapping my head around double-entry bookkeeping.

Comment: This is the correct answer- you are not buying groceries, you are loaning your friend $200.  From your household finances perspective, it doesn't matter that your friend immediately turns around and buys groceries with borrowed money.  They could burn the cash, it would still be a "Loan to friend" from the perspective of your accounts.